# Link in community user's chatter email redirects to incorrect login

Tags: chatter, login, partner-communities

We have many users under the partner community license that use chatter via a custom web page and mobile app. Chatter works as expected and email notifications are sent to the relevant users when needed (posting, mentions, etc.).

However, the links in the emails the users receive direct them to the standard SalesForce login page instead of the community login. This prevents users from being able to login and navigate to the relevant record.

Are we missing a configuration setting somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

This is a expected behavior as of now.

A solution to this issue  is in the works, where the Admin will be able to configure the community where the links will go for a specific user profile. Keep your eye out for it in coming releases.

I have a few follow up questions, if you don't mind. Is this behavior only happening for posts/comments on non-scoped records? Does this only affect internal users?

Comment: Hi, I seem to understand from your answer that right now it is not possible for community users to navigate to the relevant page from an email link. This defeats the purpose of having email notifications. Am I missing something? Regarding your questions: this happens for all chatter notification emails received for any chatter action. This affects all community users (including external). Can you give us a bit more info as to when this feature will be available? Is it currently in the works or will we have to wait months for it?